# How do I query an fts table in sqlite for one column matching and another NOT matching a particular query?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, fts3, fts4

I have a Suggestions table(FTS4) that is used to provide suggestions for a query in Android action bar search. I need to query the table for suggestions where one column(`suggest_text_1`) matches the query text AND another column(`data_type`) does NOT match a particular query, say `2`.

My current selection text is `table_suggestions MATCH ?` and I'm trying the following selection argument text to be substituted for the `'?'` - `suggest_text_1:*S1* AND data_type:NOT 2`.

The problem is, the table is providing me any suggestions even though the data is there. Could point me in the right way to perform this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite library in Android is typically not compiled with the enhanced query syntax, so you have to use the [standard query syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_2) as something like `suggest_text_1:S1* data_type:-2`.
In SQL, this would be:

```sql
SELECT docid,
       suggest_text_1
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable MATCH 'suggest_text_1:' || ? || '* data_type:-' || ?
```

FTS supports only prefix queries; you cannot use `*` at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Yeah, I already got it, but I didn't update my answer. Thanks for answering anyway. :-)